# Is there a common place to set headerStyle, HeaderTitleStyle etc

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have simple **DrawerNavigator** which **contains multiple StackNavigator**.

My issue is, I have set of 'navigationOptions' which will be same for all 'StackNavigator'

```
const DrawerMainRoutes = DrawerNavigator({
   Stack1: { screen: Stack1 }
   Stack2: { screen: Stack2 }
   Stack3: { screen: Stack4 }
})


const Sack1 = StackNavigator({
   Stack1: { 
     screen: View 
   },
   navigationOptions: {
     headerStyle: 'Blue',
     headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff', },
     headerTintColor: '#fff',
     headerLeft: <MenuIcon />
   }
})
```

Is there a better way set this **navigationOptions** common for every StackNavigator

Answer (score 1):

The `navigationOptions` should be defined in a separate variable, then you can reuse it:

```
const navigationOptions = {
  headerStyle: 'Blue',
  headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff', },
  headerTintColor: '#fff',
  headerLeft: <MenuIcon />
}

const Sack1 = StackNavigator({
   Stack1: {
     screen: View 
   },
   navigationOptions
})

const Sack2 = StackNavigator({
   Stack2: {
     screen: View 
   },
   navigationOptions
})

...
```

Or you can create a StackNavigator creator function:

```
const createStackNavigator = (routeOptions) =>
  StackNavigator(routeOptions, {
    navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: 'Blue',
      headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff', },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerLeft: <MenuIcon />
  })

const Stack1 = createStackNavigator({ Stack1: { screen: View } })
const Stack2 = createStackNavigator({ Stack2: { screen: View } })
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue is same. Suppose if "Stack1" contains 5 screens. I have to copy paste "navigationOptions" in all 5 screens. And same to do with other Stacks.

Comment: The StackNavigator has a second argument called StackNavigatorConfig. It's a dictionary, you can define a navigationOptions key in it with your default configuration and it applies to every screen in the stack.